# How to transpose rows in a table to columns (using outer apply, dynamic query )?

Tags: .net, sql-server, oracle, transpose, outer-apply

I have an Order Table and a OrderRow table in MS-SQL DB.

```
OrderNO *(Order)*
--------       
100
101
102 

Product    Qty  **(OrderRow)**
----      ---
Item1     25
Item2     50
Item3      3
Item4     10
----- n items
```

I want to write a select query which will return a result like this.

```
OrderNo   Item1   Item2    Item3   Item4
----------------------------------------------
 100         25      50       3      10
```

Currently my Query is below.

```
Select Order.OrderNo,[Item1].Qty , [Item2].Qty from Order  
Outer Apply 
(Select  Qty  from OrderRow where Order.OrderNo=OrderRow.OrderNo
                                  and Product=Item1
            ) as [Item1]
Outer Apply 
(Select  Qty  from OrderRow where Order.OrderNo=OrderRow.OrderNo
                                  and Product=Item2
            ) as [Item2]
```

But problem is that the number items in the OrderRow is not a fixed number.

How i can qrite a query that will work for any number of items ?..

Answer (score 0):

If the number of rows were fixed and known, you could use [PIVOT/UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) to achieve this. However, with your kind of problem, the only possible way is to implement a dynamic query and assign the item name as the column alias. You can learn more about dynamic pivot generators [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/).

Comment: can you help me in writing a procedure for this ?